# ¿Cómo eliminar o reemplazar los caracteres de un string en Javascript o jquery?

Tags: javascript, regex

Necesito una ayuda con reemplazar o eliminar lo que esta a la par de CustomPages menos el caracter / puede ser cualquier caracter que salga a la par de CustomPages.

tengo esta cadena de string:

```
var url = 'https://localhost:7125/error404CustomPages/logout';
```

y la quiero que quede asi:

```
'https://localhost:7125/CustomPages/logout'
```

ya utilice replace y no me funciono

```js
var url = 'https://localhost:7125/error404CustomPages/logout';
url = url.replace(/(\/CustomPages)[^/]+/, '');
console.log(url);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Podes lograrlo usando esta RegEx:

```
\/[^\/]*(CustomPages)[^\/]*\/
```

Que representa:

- `\/`: El caracter `/`
- `[^\/]*`: Cero o mas caracteres distintos de `/`
- `CustomPages`: La cadena "CustomPages"
- `[^\/]*`: Cero o mas caracteres distintos de `/`
- `\/`: El caracter `/`

#### Demo:

```js
var url = 'https://localhost:7125/error404CustomPages/logout';
url = url.replace(/\/[^\/]*(CustomPages)[^\/]*\//, '/$1/');
console.log(url);
```

Answer (score 0):

Aquí un ejemplo sin `Regex`

Se separa la cadena con un `split("/")`, se mapea buscando cada subcadena que contenga `CustomPages`, si la subcadena la contiene se reemplaza por `CustomPages`, en caso contrario se deja la misma subcadena. Finalmente se vuelve a unir todo.

```js
var url = 'https://localhost:7125/error404CustomPages/logout';

var result = url.split("/").map(a=>a.includes("CustomPages") ? "CustomPages" : a).join("/");

console.log(result)
```